# Implicit declaration of function 'FBSDK_NOT_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER' is invalid in C99 Expected ')'

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoapods, facebook-ios-sdk, facebook-sdk-4.x

I'm using Facebook SDK for iOS 4.6.0 and just today above error encountered after updating cocoapods to 0.38.2. I'm not sure this error has anything to do with  cocoapods.

Error screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I had the same issue. The problem appeared because, I was connecting both "*ParseFacebookUtils*" (which was loading "*Facebook-iOS-SDK*" (which is the deprecated version) and "*FBSDKCoreKit*" separately.

"*Facebook-iOS-SDK*" and "*FBSDKCoreKit*" both have "*FBSDKMacros.h*" which has different declarations of "**FBSDK_NOT_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER**" and that is why message in XCode appear.

What I suggest, if "*ParseFacebookUtils*" is not in your podfile list, check which cocoaPod loading "*Facebook-iOS-SDK*" and try to update it with the newer version of that framework.

If "*ParseFacebookUtils*" is your case than easily change it to '*ParseFacebookUtilsV4*'

And surely don't forget to run '**pod update**' to make all changes active

Hope this helps.

Comment: You're right. However, I imported Facebook SDK frameworks instead of using it from cocoapods and it worked like a charm! This way I can use latest SDK versions.

Comment: Hi, I am having the same issue. I tried changing my ParseFacebookUtils to V4, and it came with a whole bunch of new errors.

Comment: Facebook and Parse need to sort out their libraries and documentation. You would never guess they are the same company.  I get the following error when I try this ``` 'FBSDKInternalUtility.h' file not found```

Comment: Excellent! Installing ParseFacebookUtilsV4 instead of ParseFacebookUtils solved my problem.

Answer (score 14):

Delete FBSDKMacros.h from Facebook-iOS-SDK directory because whatever declared here is also declared in FBSDKMacros.h in FBSDKCoreKit directory and your code will be working fine.

Answer (score 1):

I removed the reference FBSDKMacros.h from the Facebook-iOS-SDK directory instead of deleting it. This did the trick for me.