# FBSDKCoreKit pod file won't compile, missing parenthesis ')' in FBSDKAppEventsState.m

Tags: facebook, ios9, xcode7, fbsdk

[image: Error that shows when trying to build]

[image: line in FBSDKAppEventsState.m where error originates. cursor is where it says parenthesis should go]

Steps to reproduce

1. Updated cocoapods
2. Build project

I updated cocoapods to 0.38.2 then ran pod update. Built my project and the error is in FBSDKCorekit, and more specifically in FBSDKAppEventsState.m. The error states that there is a missing ')' but it doesn't appear that it is missing. I've removed all the FBSDK related pods and added them back and I get the same result. Screenshots are attached

SDK version:  'FBSDKCoreKit', '~> 4.7'

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32877681/implicit-declaration-of-function-fbsdk-not-designated-initializer-is-invalid-i